# DynamoDB streams - write data back into table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Consider the following architecture:

```
write -> DynamoDB table -> stream -> Lambda -> write metadata item to same table
```

It could be used for many, many awsome situations, e.g table and item level aggregations. I've seen this architecture promoted in several tech talks by official AWS engineers.

---

But doesn't writing metadata item add new item to stream and run Lambda again?

How to avoid infinite loop? Is there a way to avoid metadata write appearing in stream?

Or is spending 2 stream and Lambda requests inevitable with this architecture? (we're charged per request) I.e exit Lambda function early if it's metadata item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As triggering an AWS Lambda function from a DynamoDB stream is a binary option (on/off), it's not possible to only trigger the AWS Lambda function for certain writes to the table. So your AWS Lambda function will be called again for the items it just wrote to the DynamoDB table. The important bit is to have logic in place in your AWS Lambda function to detect that it wrote that data and to not write data in that case again. Otherwise you'd get the mentioned infinite loop, which would be a really unfortunate situation, especially if it would went unnoticed.

Answer (score 1):

Currently dynamo DB does not offer condition based subscription to stream, so yes Dynamo DB will execute your lambda function in an infinite loop, currently the only solution is to limit the time your lambda function execute, you can use multiple lambda functions, one lambda function would be there just to check whether a metadata was written or not, I'm sharing a cloud architecture diagram of how you can achieve it,

[image: Dynamo DB same table metadata insertion reference]

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but hopefully people looking for a more demonstrative answer will find this useful.

Suppose you want to process records where you want to add to an item up to a certain threshold, you could have an if condition that checks that and processes or skips the record, e.g.

This code assumes you have an attribute "Type" for each of your entities / object types - this was recommended to me by Rick Houlihan himself but you could also check if an attribute exists i.e. `"<your-attribute>" in record["dynamodb"]["NewImage"]` - and you are designing with PK and SK as generic primary and sort key names.

```
threshold = (os.environ.get("THRESHOLD"))


def get_value():
    response = table.query(KeyConditionExpression=Key('PK').eq(<your-pk>))
    value = response['Items']['<your-attribute>'] if 'Items' in response else 0
    return value


def your_aggregation_function():
    # Your aggregation logic here
    # Write back to the table with a put_item call once done


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    for record in event['Records']:
        if record['eventName'] != "REMOVE" and record["dynamodb"]["NewImage"]["Type'] == <your-entity-type>:
            # Query the table to extract the attribute value
            attribute_value = get_value(record["dynamodb"]["Keys"]["PK"]["S"])
            if attribute_value < threshold:
                # Send to your aggregation function
```

Having the conditions in place in the lambda handler (or you could change where to suit your needs) prevents the infinite loop mentioned.

You may want additional checks in the update expression to make sure two (or more) concurrent lambda are not writing the same object. I suggest you use a `date = # timestamp defined in the lambda` and add this in the SK, or if you cant, have an "EventDate" attribute in your item so that yo ucould add `ConditionExpression` or `UpdateExpression SET if_not_exists(#attribute, :date)`

The above will guarantee that your lambda is [idempotent](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-function-idempotent/).

Comment: But if `PK=post#<id> and SK=meta` contains e.g vote count and `PK=post#<id> and SK=vote#<timestamp>` are votes, Lambda would update same item (count attribute on meta) every time. I don't think time exist check helps here. Any ideas how to make that idempotent?

Answer (score 0):

Since 2021 you can now filter specific conditions to get triggered:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-eventfiltering.html

So on your example, you can add a condition to avoid loop.